# Arrastar Formular mas mover 5 células

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu preciso de arrastar a formula que tenho em "Sum Values" para as restantes semanas mas automaticamente o Excel cria-me a linha que tem os valores em vermelho, existe alguma forma de arrastar as formular e ficar como a linha verde?

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/6qtnS37j/Excel.png]

Answer (score 0):

Depois de varias tentativas descobri, fica aqui se alguem precisar
=SUM(INDEX(13:13,match(F$15,11:11,0)):INDEX(13:13,match(F$15,11:11,0)+4))